# assimp, how to save compressed assbin file

Tags: c++, opengl, assets, assimp

I am using assimp to convert some .obj files to the proprietary format assbin, in order to load them faster in the engine I'm writing.
My code is:

```
Assimp::Exporter Exporter;
Assimp::Importer Importer;
const aiExportFormatDesc* format = Exporter.GetExportFormatDescription(11);
const aiScene* pScene;

printf("Converting: Arbor Obj/Arbor");
pScene = Importer.ReadFile("Objects/Arbor Obj/Arbor.obj", aiProcess_Triangulate | aiProcess_GenSmoothNormals | aiProcess_FlipUVs);
Exporter.Export(pScene, format->id, "Objects/Arbor Obj/Arbor.ass", aiProcess_Triangulate | aiProcess_GenSmoothNormals | aiProcess_FlipUVs);
```

and it works flawlessly, but I don't know how to save the assbin file compacted.
I do know, by the documentation found online that this is possible, but I do not know how to achieve this.

Comment: What kind of compression you're talking about? Why do you think it should be there? After quick look at assbin writer source I don't see any hint on compression support. Of cource you can use general purpose compression like zlib/lz4/zstd/... but it isn't really related to assimp.

Comment: One of the texts that made think of that was this piece here:

Comment: const char* AICMD_MSG_DUMP_HELP = 
"assimp dump <model> [<out>] [-b] [-s] [-z] [common parameters]\n"
"\t -b Binary output \n"
"\t -s Shortened  \n"
"\t -z Compressed  \n"
"\t[See the assimp_cmd docs for a full list of all common parameters]  \n"
"\t -cfast    Fast post processing preset, runs just a few important steps \n"
"\t -cdefault Default post processing: runs all recommended steps\n"
"\t -cfull    Fires almost all post processing steps \n"
;

#include "../../code/assbin_chunks.h"

FILE* out = NULL;
bool shortened = false;

Comment: // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Compress a binary dump file (beginning at offset head_size)
void CompressBinaryDump(const char* file, unsigned int head_size)
{
 // for simplicity ... copy the file into memory again and compress it there
 FILE* p = fopen(file,"r");
 fseek(p,0,SEEK_END);
 const uint32_t size = ftell(p);
 fseek(p,0,SEEK_SET);

 if (size<head_size) {
  fclose(p);
  return;
 }

 uint8_t* data = new uint8_t[size];
 fread(data,1,size,p);

Comment: uLongf out_size = (uLongf)((size-head_size) * 1.001 + 12.);

Comment: I'm sorry about the text alltogether, but I'm new to posting in Stack Overflow and didn't manage to properly past code in it. Tried <CTRL K> but to no effect, as  well as <TAB> and putting 4 spaces before or after the text...)

Comment: Comments can't have code blocks, it would be better to edit your question to include required code. But no matter, I suppose you're talking about standalone convertor tool, which performs compression itself. In theory `AssbinExporter.cpp` have code for compression (simple zlib deflate, for that matter - not really sure it would be best), but there is actually no way to enable that parameter, and comment says only "until properties are introduced for exporters", which I suppose never happened. As it is zlib in best case, I still think it would be better to implement compression elsewhere.

Comment: Also, there is this part of the function ExportSceneAssbin class, specifically in the WriteBinaryDump function:


 // Up to here the data is uncompressed. For compressed files, the rest
    // is compressed using standard DEFLATE from zlib.
    if (compressed)
       {
  AssbinChunkWriter uncompressedStream( NULL, 0 );
  WriteBinaryScene( &uncompressedStream, pScene );

Comment: As I see it, the only benefit of saving in compression-enabled assbin is so other assimp-based tools could still load it. If that's what you need, I don't see better ways then modifying assimp, wrapping output into modified header like standalone convertor does, or patching resulting 'file' (modifying header and replacing data with deflated one).

Comment: Sorry, didn't saw your answer before posting the rest of my response

Comment: I understand what you've said, I saw that comment in the code myself. This will probably what I'll do. Thanks for the answer!!

Comment: How can I vote for your answer as good and helpful?? (still new to this)

Answer (score 0):

At the moment writing compressed assimp.xml or assimp.bin format is not supported. See this [feature request](https://github.com/assimp/assimp/issues/2196) fir follow the progress on it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll do, and will try some other paths too. I'll post if find anything usefull during my research